# Clojure embed var to String, a alternative way? Like sprintf way?

Tags: clojure

```
 (str "I don't know what " (:name a) " eats."))
```

I know this is the right way to construct a string with variables.
But is there a way similar to this?

```
(str "I dont know what %s eats." (:name a))
```

I tried and this is not valid syntax, but is there a similar way in Clojure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diego Basch mentioned `format`, which is a good answer.  You can also use `cl-format`:

```
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "I don't know what ~a eats." "Joe")
```

With `nil` as the second argument, this returns a string.  Other options for the second argument will cause the string to be written somewhere.

`format` uses `java.lang.String.format`.  `cl-format` is a Clojure version of Common Lisp's `format`.  For formatting strings, their functionality is very similar, but there are a few things that `cl-format` can do well that Clojure's `format` doesn't.  Simple example--printing `nil`:

```
(format "I don't know what %s eats." nil)
;=> "I don't know what null eats."

(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "I don't know what ~a eats." nil)
;=> "I don't know what nil eats."
```

Answer (score 4):

`format` is what you want. For example:

```
(format "I don't know what %s eats." "Joe")
```

=> `"I don't know what Joe eats."`