# Lightweight Clojure library for simple string templating?

Tags: string, clojure, template-engine

I'm looking for a (preferably small) Clojure library that is available in clojars which allows me to replace simple templates in strings such as:

"Hello my name is ${name}"

where `${name}` should be replaced by the template engine. In Java I usually use [JMTE](https://code.google.com/p/jmte/) that works perfectly. I know that I can probably use it from Clojure as well but I wonder if there's something that is more Clojure friendly/idiomatic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are quite a lot of templating libraries. Some general purpose ones are:

- [clostache](https://github.com/fhd/clostache)
- [comb](https://github.com/weavejester/comb)
- [selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer)

Note: If you just need to have some clever formatting, you have the standard library [clojure.pprint](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) with the `cl-format` function and `clojure.core/format` which is the wrapper around `java.util.Formatter`.

Comment: To see a use of  `cl-format` look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512798/#28513452)

Comment: It's idiomatic Clojure to use the host libraries when suitable, it seems like use clojure.core/format would be a good fit here.

Comment: This is an OLD thread, but for folks using babashka, selmer.parser is included. You can see example usage here: https://nextjournal.com/borkdude/babashka-selmer

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`<<`](https://clojure.github.io/core.incubator/clojure.core.strint-api.html#clojure.core.strint/%3C%3C) string interpolation macro  from the [core.incubator](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator) project.

To use it, add `[org.clojure/core.incubator "0.1.4"]` as a dependency in your `project.clj` file. (Note: check core.incubator's [GitHub page](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator) for the latest installation instructions.)

Example use:

```
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.core.strint :refer [<<]]))

(def my-name "XYZ")
(<< "My name is ~{my-name}.")
; Returns: "My name is XYZ."

(let [x 3
      y 4]
  (<< "~{x} plus ~{y} equals ~(+ x y)."))
; Returns: "3 plus 4 equals 7."
```

Note the difference between the use of curly braces `~{}` and parentheses `~()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://cemerick.com/2009/12/04/string-interpolation-in-clojure.html).

Maybe that is what your looking for.

Comment: Looks promising but I'd prefer if it would be available in clojars

Comment: Why? It's available in the incubator project of the **clojure.core**. You can only get more official if they decided to incorporate this library in Clojure itself. As far as I know none of the **clojure.core** projects are in Clojars, including Clojure, ClojureScript, core.async, nREPL, and test.check.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a library, found this example in [Clojure, the Essential Reference](https://www.manning.com/books/clojure-the-essential-reference) book.

> `replace` could be used to implement a simple textual substitution
>   system. An input string contains special placeholders that the system
>   can identify and replace from a list of known substitutions:

```
(def text "You provided the following: user {usr} password {pwd}")
(def sub {"{usr}" "'rb075'" "{pwd}" "'xfrDDjsk'"})

(transduce
  (comp
    (replace sub)
    (interpose " "))
  str
  (clojure.string/split text #"\s"))

;; "You provided the following: user 'rb075' password 'xfrDDjsk'"
```

Comment: Note: this only works for space-separated terms, so e.g. `hi{there}` won't work.